# C# Retrieve array from FireStore but im getting System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

im trying to retrieve all documents data in a collection but array's returning System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] how can i fix this?

here's my code

```
async void getData()
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        Query allCitiesQuery = database.Collection("siparisler");
        QuerySnapshot allCitiesQuerySnapshot = await allCitiesQuery.GetSnapshotAsync();
        foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in allCitiesQuerySnapshot.Documents)
        {

            listBox1.Items.Add("_________________________________________");
            Dictionary<string, object> city = documentSnapshot.ToDictionary ();
            foreach (var pair in city)
            {

                listBox1.Items.Add(pair.Key + ": " + pair.Value);
               
                
            }

        }


    }
```

[Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsGqX.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO . Please dont use images for code, exceptions or example data: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: `Dictionary<string, object>` so.. you are trying to print `object` directly without knowing the actual type? the default `ToString()` method for most c# classes are printing their own name. on your case the `object` is a `List<string>`. you have to expand it into a single`string` somehow.

Comment: What is the type of `listBox1` object?